# Solving $ax + b = 0 \pmod{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

What is the most efficient algorithmic way of solving x in: $ax + b = 0 \pmod{n}$, where a, b, and n are extremely large integers?

A simple example:

$56473x + 36482 \equiv 0 \pmod{4536}$.

I find answers with examples particularly helpful.

Comment: Examples, *extremely large* numbers and finite space for human-written text do not go well together.

Comment: @The method will be implemented in code, so any answers showing this will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ax+b\equiv 0\pmod m\iff x\equiv -ba^{-1}\pmod m$

When $\gcd(a,m)=1$ then $a^{-1}$ is ensured to exists and you can get it via the Extended Euclid algorithm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm

```
ExtendedEuclidAlgorithm(a,m) --> d,u,v
```

Where $\begin{cases}\gcd(a,m)=d\\au+mv=d\end{cases}$

So when $d=1$ then $au=1-mv\equiv 1\pmod m$

Meaning that $u\equiv a^{-1}\pmod m$

---

Let's apply it to your equation: $56473x+36482\equiv 0\pmod{4536}$

```
ExtendedEuclidAlgorithm(56473,4536) --> 1,1129,-14056
```

So the solutions are

$x\equiv -36482\times 1129\equiv 3238\pmod{4536}$

Comment: Could you show how you get from the Euclid output to your final line?

Comment: I just calculate $-ba^{-1}$ or $-bu$ if you prefer modulo 4536.

Comment: Could you show how you calculate those please?

Comment: I don't get it ?! You say you will implement it in code, so I just do x=(-b*u)%m.

Comment: Ahh I forgot to mod -bu

Comment: Alternately you can do x=((-b%m)*u)%m to avoid multiplying too big numbers.

Answer (score 1):

$$4536\mid 56473 x +36482 - 12\cdot 4536 x - 8\cdot 4536 = 2041x+194$$

so $2041x+194 = 4536y$ for some integer $y$. Thus $$2041|4536y-194 - 2\cdot 2041y = 454y-194 = 2(227y-97)$$
so $2041 \mid 227y-97$ and thus $227y-97 = 2041 z$ for some integer $z$. So we have: $$227\mid 2041z+97 - 9\cdot 227 z = 97-2z$$
Now we have $227t = 97-2z$ for some integer $t$ and thus $$2|-227t+97+228t-96 = t+1$$

So $t= 2s-1$ for some integer $s$. Now we go backward:

$$z=162-227s$$

$$y=1457-2041s$$

$$x= 3238-4536s$$

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on that please?

Comment: I'm working on it.

Comment: where does the 12 and 8 come from in the first line?

Comment: divide 56473 and ... with 4536

Comment: Do you think you could adapt your answer to show a case where x is simply an integer?

Comment: For example, x = 435.

Comment: But 435 is not a solution.

Comment: You can change a and b. And n